# split string by comma so that each sentence will be a separate string

Tags: python, string, list

I want to split my string in separate sentences.
My code is below

```
 import tensorflow as tf
 import pandas as pd 

 text = 'My cat is a great cat, this is very nice, you are doing great job'

 text = text.split(',')
```

Output:

```
 ['My cat is a great cat', ' this is very nice', ' you are doing great job']
```

But I want this output to be

```
 ['My cat is a great cat'] ['this is very nice'] ['you are doing great job']
```

is it possible??

Comment: Can't you just access each index of the list as its own string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's possible, we have answers already given above but
to match exact expected output as mentioned above use below:

```
inputlist = "apple,banana,cherry"
print(*[[s] for s in inputlist.split(',')],end=" ")
```

output:

```
['apple'] ['banana'] ['cherry']
```

Answer (score 2):

You just turn into a list of list with this

```py
text = 'My cat is a great cat, this is very nice, you are doing great job'
text = [[x] for x in text.split(", ")]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```py
text = list(map(lambda x: [x], text.split(',')))
```

```
print(text)

[['My cat is a great cat'], [' this is very nice'], [' you are doing great job']]
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to insert each item in a list. *You can use `str.strip()` for removing spaces.*

```
>>> text = 'My cat is a great cat, this is very nice, you are doing great job'
>>> [[i.strip()] for i in text.split(',')]

[['My cat is a great cat'], ['this is very nice'], ['you are doing great job']]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this, this will put every element of the list into a list

```py
text = 'My cat is a great cat, this is very nice, you are doing great job'

 text = [ [i] for i in text.split(',')]
```

Answer (score 2):

Didn't know if you wanted this in `tensorflow`. But if so, here's how you do it,

```
import tensorflow as tf

text = tf.constant('My cat is a great cat, this is very nice, you are doing great job')

tf.strings.split(text, sep=',')[:, tf.newaxis]
```

Also, I wonder if your question was about splitting *and* getting rid of space after the comma. If that's what you needed,

```
tf.strings.split(text, sep=', ')
```